# Comparing strings does not work php

Tags: php, string, comparison, explode, login-script

When I execute this code the user is correct but the pass is not, why is it? It's driving me insane.

```
<?php
$user = $_POST['myusername'];
$pass = $_POST['mypassword'];
$file_handle = fopen("db.txt", "rb");
while (!feof($file_handle)){
    $line_of_text = fgets($file_handle);
    $parts = explode('=', $line_of_text);
    if($parts[0] == $user){
        echo $parts[0];
    }
    if($parts[1] == $pass){
        echo $parts[1];
    }
}
fclose($file_handle);
?>
```

Comment: Does your file have a return at the end of the line? If so, then fgets() is reading that as well, and it will be a character in $parts[1]. Test should be if(trim($parts[1]) == $pass){

Comment: Post example data that fails with your code.

Comment: Unless you are doing it just for learning purposes you should really consider using a database for this instead of a flat file! Besides that, if the file is not too large (it will be loaded into memory at once) you can quickly iterate over the lines: `foreach(file('db.txt') as $line)`

Comment: Try `if(trim($parts[0]) == $user)` and `if(trim($parts[1]) == $pass)`

Comment: you are using data-file handling in the world of dbms

Comment: Thank you so much, I was going crazy already. the trim function did the job.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this , you might be getting white space in your inputs  or values from file

```
if(trim($parts[0]) == trim($user)){
    echo $parts[0];
}
if(trim($parts[1]) == trim($pass)){
    echo $parts[1];
}
```